# React-Select - Custom Option issue with incompatible props/props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-brook-oe3qz3?file=/src/App.tsx

This quick sandbox is an example of what I'm attempting to do (at a larger scale). The actual component works as intended (as seen in the sandbox browser) but in the actual project the error (as seen by hovering over `Option` on line 27 will not allow for me to continue development.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding in regards to my interface and what's expected within `components.Option`.

I don't know what context I can provide to help outside of the sandbox, but if I've missed anything I'll provide.

Comment: You need to change the type of props to `FC<OptionProps<SelectInputOptionInterface>>` for the option component. It should work after that.